# nhibernate optimistic lock / handling staleobject exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, concurrency

I have an object in an object tree which is "secured" by nhibernate optimistic lock feature.

If I catch the staleobjectexception occured in transaction commit, I have to traverse the tree by hand, but if the transaction additional commits some independent objects - these are lost...:(

Both leads me to believe that the error in the architecture

But what are the right approaches?

Single transactions for every object tree, don't build the conflict handling on the staleobjectexception,  ...?

I have a bad feeling about my current approaches...

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to append my view, my experience.

*(So it do not have to be the answer to your question). I like that you/we do question our own code, our own design/architecture - which is a **good** sign. Bad is, if we omit that...*

#### Is there error?

Here is a set of rules, which should be followed: [Best Coding Practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_Coding_Practices).

One of these is (extract):

[Keep the code simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_Coding_Practices#Keep_the_code_simple)

> The code that a programmer writes should be simple. Complicated logic
>   for achieving a simple thing should be kept to a minimum since the
>   code might be modified by another programmer in the future. The logic
>   one programmer implemented may not make perfect sense to another. So,
>   always keep the code as simple as possible

Other words: If it does not seem to be good architecture, it is NOT. If you do not like it, others won't as well.

#### Versioning, how to *(a suggestion)*

Well, below I stated some common approaches, which we do apply for versioning.

- Versioning is useful only for Business objects (which should never be more then 20% of all objects in the domain). Other (CodeLists like currencies, countries...) are not versioned.
- Each object has its own management (CRUD operations) for its tree. In that case, only this *root* object is versioned. E.g. if Address could exist only with a Person, both objects are stored during one walkthroug (creation or amending of the Person). Only the Person has a Version

And that's it. Really, nothing more complex. But I do understand if this does not answer your question... I just wanted to append my opinion to this discussion.

Comment: If that helped anyhow, then great ;) Enjoy NHiberante